# webapp2_extras.jinja2 compile template from variable

Tags: google-app-engine, jinja2, webapp2

Having this property to get the instance of the class jinja2

```
@webapp2.cached_property
    def jinja2(self):
        # Returns an instance of :class:`Jinja2` from the app registry.
        return jinja2.get_jinja2(app=self.app)
```

Reference : http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/jinja2.html

I'm able to see that the returning class has the module Templates but I don't know how to import it.

I want to be able to load this module out of the returning class so I can do something like: `temp = Template('{{name}}')`

Help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did.

```
values = { 'name' : 'user1791567' }

import sys
mod = sys.modules['jinja2.environment']

_template = mod.Template('{{name}}')

self.jinja2.render_template(_template, **values)
```

And worked!!!..

Comment: you can just 'import jinja2', no need to mess with sys.modules